# segmentation fault php7 symfony cli command using soap

Tags: soap, segmentation-fault, symfony, php-7

I am tring to upgrade to php7 and symfony3 from php5.6 and symfony2 resp. I have some symfony console commands which uses soap to request third party apis.

After upgrading to php7 and php7.0-soap, but command fails with segmentation fault. I tried debugging with gdb, below is the trace. Looks like this is the issue with php7.0-soap ? What is the solution ?

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00005555557bc4db in zend_hash_destroy ()
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00005555557bc4db in zend_hash_destroy ()
#1  0x00007fffecbbe141 in delete_type_persistent () from /usr/lib/php/20151012/soap.so
#2  0x00005555557bc5dd in zend_hash_destroy ()
#3  0x00007fffecbc55f1 in ?? () from /usr/lib/php/20151012/soap.so
#4  0x00007fffecbc565f in ?? () from /usr/lib/php/20151012/soap.so
#5  0x00005555557bc4d2 in zend_hash_destroy ()
#6  0x00007fffecb95f0b in zm_shutdown_soap () from /usr/lib/php/20151012/soap.so
#7  0x00005555557b25f3 in module_destructor ()
#8  0x00005555557ab08c in ?? ()
#9  0x00005555557bd048 in zend_hash_graceful_reverse_destroy ()
#10 0x00005555557ac055 in zend_shutdown ()
#11 0x000055555574fb3b in php_module_shutdown ()
#12 0x000055555563d796 in main ()
```

Comment: I'm getting a similar seg fault:

`Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007f85375094bb in zend_hash_destroy ()
   from /etc/httpd/modules/libphp-7.0.so
(gdb) backtrace
#0  0x00007f85375094bb in zend_hash_destroy ()
   from /etc/httpd/modules/libphp-7.0.so
#1  0x00007f852e356a3e in ?? () from /usr/lib64/php/7.0/modules/soap.so
#2  0x00007f85375095bd in zend_hash_destroy ()
   from /etc/httpd/modules/libphp-7.0.so`

(and more)

I also found this: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=71931

Answer (score 4):

you can't use `WSDL_CACHE_MEMORY` (or `WSDL_CACHE_BOTH`) in PHP7 for the time being: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=71931

use `WSDL_CACHE_DISK` instead by setting `soap.wsdl_cache` in `php.ini`, or - if you don't have access to `php.ini` - using `ini_set`:

```
ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache', WSDL_CACHE_DISK);
```